# How can I capture the audio output with GStreamer?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, gstreamer

I’d like to capture *only* the output of a machine using [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org).

Using the following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v alsasrc ! wavenc ! filesink location="output.wav"
```

I can record the microphone, but how can I record/capture just the audio output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to capture the output of your soundcard, you'll have to use pulsesrc and set the device property to your soundcard's analog-stereo monitor source. Have a look [here](http://oz9aec.net/software/gstreamer/pulseaudio-device-names).

Here the relevant source would be `alsa_output.pci-0000_80_01.0.analog-stereo.monitor` and you'd change your pipeline's input to

```
pulsesrc device = "alsa_output.pci-0000_80_01.0.analog-stereo.monitor"
```